# How does a computer calculate matrix scalar multiplication order of operations (flops)

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point

I am trying to understand the number of flops in the Householder QR factorization. In one line of the algorithm, it says
\begin{gather*}
v = v / \lVert v \rVert_2
\end{gather*}
I was wondering what the order of operations for a computer was. In other words, does it compute the norm first, so for an $n$ length vector we have
$$
\lVert v \rVert_2 = \sqrt{v_1^2 + ... + v_n^2} \Rightarrow v = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{v_1^2 + ... + v_{n}^2}}\begin{bmatrix}v_1, & ... &, v_{n}\end{bmatrix}^T
$$
taking I believe $3n$ flops, or is it re-computing the norm at each entry of the vector, ie
$$
 v = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 /  \sqrt{v_1^2 + ... + v_{n}^2}, & ... &, v_{n} /  \sqrt{v_1^2 + ... + v_{n}^2}\end{bmatrix}^T
$$
taking $2n^2$ flops?

Comment: You would certainly compute the norm only once

Comment: thank you! so does this mean it is unnecessary to store scalar values, ie this line is equivalent to saying c = norm{v}; v = v / c?

Comment: Well yes, if this is pseudo code.

Comment: If that root is actually part of the computation, then the implementation is not the most efficient. The only square root that is necessary is $\sqrt{v_2^2+...+v_n^2}$, and while normalization of $v$ is theoretically nice, it gets absorbed into a factor $\beta$ as in $I-\beta vv^T$, which is applies as $(I-\beta vv^T)x=x-(\beta(v^Tx))v$.